# Why my git commands doesnt override my local changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

Im working on a Ruby project and just made some bad decisions about migrations and entities.

Ok, I will get the content of my master branch and override the bad job I did.

I use:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

But the files I added locally still are there. What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reset when you didn't commit anything (as I believe is the case here).

Just call `git checkout .` to get rid of any uncommitted changes.

The long story is:

Git stores changes in few "stages".

- When you change a file, then it's unstaged change, revert it with `git checkout <changed_file>` or `git checkout .` for every file
- when you stage a file `git add <filename>` or a part of a file even `git add -p` then it's so called staged, ready to commit. You can still go back with `git reset HEAD <file>`
- when you commit, the commit is created in your local branch, this is when you would use

  - `git reset origin/master` to get rid of the commits, but keep the changes (back to first point)
  - `git reset --hard origin/master` the same as above, but clear all the changes

So for your case, to get rid of local, uncommitted changes: `git checkout .` and, in case you have some commits you don't want `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: It didnt nothing. I want to override all my local changes with the remote data.

Comment: I did everything, but all the unstaged files continues there. They are not being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The secret here is to use a git clean -f to delete all the non-staged files.